# Connecting spring boot application in one docker container to a Cassandra database in another container

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra

I need to connect spring boot application in one docker container to a Cassandra database in another container.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways.

- "scripted" approach, where you first `docker run` cassandra container, then you `docker run` your app. You have to make sure first container exposes ports second container can connect to, or while starting second container reference ports from first by name
- use docker compose, that should more or less look like this:

```
version: '2'

services:
  cassandra:
    image: cassandra:3.11.5
    ports:
      - 7000:7000

  springapp:
    image: springapp:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      CASSANDRA_CONTACTPOINTS: 127.0.0.1
      CASSANDRA_PORT: 7000
```